# Simple Selenium Webdriver importing doesnt work

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

```
**from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.chrome("./chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I wrote the above code in visual studio code; however, every time I do this, this error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'browser' is not defined
```

I downloaded the Selenium library and web driver matches my Chrome, but I'm unsure what to do.

I Googled and YouTubed it for almost 3 hours and it does not work at all.

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Start learning Selenium from any of the online tutorials.

Always careful on case sensitive while coding through Selenium with Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("<path of the chromedriver.exe>"))
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```